# Tortoise SVN Tag

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have created a TAG to freeze certain versions of directories and files in the trunk. Now I would need a report (text file) for authorities which includes revisions and **dates** of each item in the TAG. Is that possible to do?

I can see revisions and dates in GUI but it would a lot of manual work to copy paste dates from GUI to report.

Regards,
Ari

Answer (score 1):

Use svn.exe command line client for this task. For example, run

`svn list --verbose --recursive http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.8.13/`

You can also instruct the client to output XML with this command:

`svn list --xml --recursive http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.8.13/`

See [`svn list`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/list/) command line reference.